# Certificate based authentication on stock browser of Android 4.4 (Kitkat)

Tags: android, browser, webview, webkit, android-4.4-kitkat

From my application, I am launching android's default browser to open a specific link. The link which I am trying to open requires certificate based authentication. I am using the following code.

`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://intranet.dmpdev1.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);`

On the webpage it asks for username and password. And a combination of user credentials and certificate is used to authenticate the user.
The certificate is already installed in the keychain.

Till 4.3, it used to work but on 4.4 emulator it does not work.
I know that in 4.4, the underlying engine has been changed to chromium but does that mean that this functionality of certificate based authentication has been removed?

Comment: What does “it does not work” mean? It throws an error? Please tell us the error.